# Get attributes and text from Xpath query as a list

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I would like to query an html string and extract the href attribute and the text node from an hyperlink into a list (or any other dictionary).

Consider the following code:

```
from lxml import html
str = '<a href="href1"> Text1 </a>' \
      '<a href="href2"> Text2 </a>' \
      '<a href="href3"> Text3 </a>'
tree = html.fromstring(str)
items = tree.xpath('//a')

values = list()
for item in items:
    text = item.text
    href = item.get('href')
    values.append((text, href))

for text, href in values:
    print text, href
```

This works!

I wonder if it would be possible to ommit the `for item in items:` loop and get the `values` list just with an XPath query.

`tree.xpath('//a/text()')` and `tree.xpath('//a/@href')` give me either one - but I want both values in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `|` to build a compound XPath. The text and hrefs will both be returned in a single list, `items`. You can pair every two items using the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), `zip(*[iterable]*2)`. (Note, however, that this relies on the hrefs and text strings alternating):

```
from lxml import html
str = '<a href="href1"> Text1 </a>' \
      '<a href="href2"> Text2 </a>' \
      '<a href="href3"> Text3 </a>'
tree = html.fromstring(str)
items = tree.xpath('//a/text() | //a/@href')

for href, text in zip(*[iter(items)]*2):
    print text, href
```

yields

```
 Text1  href1
 Text2  href2
 Text3  href3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
zip(a, b) # [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

So according to your xpath expressions:

```
texts = tree.xpath('//a/text()')
hrefs = tree.xpath('//a/@href')
values = zip(texts, hrefs)
```